# com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler Wont Start when compiling large GWT project

Tags: gwt, compiler-construction, project

I have a fairly large GWT project with compile output Javascript of 3.5MB when it does compile. The project is not modularized and does not use RunAsync. As of Thursday 8/9/2013 my project was compiling just fine in all the development environments (as well as on build servers) for all my developers. But starting Friday (8/9/13) none of these environment will compile. The java sources compile just fine but the build just stops just as it tries to run the com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.

Some facts:
1. GWT Versions (I have projects that are on 2.3 and 2.5 and all wont compile any more)
2. There are no significant size changes from the day before when the projects compile fine without any problems
3. Compiles are not working for even for single browser (USER-AGENT) and single locale
4. Smaller GWT projects -- including new projects created just to test compiling; work just fine and compile OK
5. I have tried on both 64bit and 32bit platforms with RAM in excess of 12GB on dev boxes
6. All dev environments and build servers are windows based

Any ideas on what has changed and what I can do to make com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler fire again for these projects.

I am most disturbed by the almost synchronized-like in which all dev environments stopped working on the same day with not as much as a change in a single line of code in some of the projects.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You said you tried building with multiple machines. Do they all share files over some version control system (eg: Git, SVN, CVS, etc.)? If so, may it be a change from one of the recent commits that made it stop working?

Comment: Yes the multiple dev machines all share the same svn repository. Still stumped about what it could be that makes GWTCompiler stop working completely